# Related to ListSelectionListener

Tags: java, swing, jtable, listselectionlistener

I used ListSelectionListener to listen the selection of a JTable to perform other task related with the selected item in the table. but why the following code executed twice at one selection in the beginning and many times times after that table is being updated?

```
 public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) 
    System.out.println(tablelist.getSelectedIndex());       
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

because [ListSelectionListene](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html)r from [ListSelectionModel interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ListSelectionModel.html) always firing two events

```
int firstIndex = e.getFirstIndex();
int lastIndex = e.getLastIndex();
```

everything in the [Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html)

Comment: +1 and also consider reading the value of `e.getValueIsAdjusting()`

Comment: Yes it always fires two events.But my scenario is like this:               1)I have written a database function which will return a model for Jtable.2)I will call that function and i am setting my customised listener to the model returned by the function.3)Later,when database is updated with new rows,step 2 is repeated.Now in this case,the following code is executed many times:

 public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) 
    System.out.println(tablelist.getSelectedIndex());       
 }

Comment: have to split to the 1) Database --> only changed value from JTable Cell could be saved, 2) JTables View v.s. TableModel (all changes must be done on EDT) 3) minimalize Listeners impact to the Database v.s. JTable